# Octagon corner animation

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to recreate this effect `https://jsfiddle.net/bfm34b9f/1/light/` without any border hacks, so that it works on all types of backgrounds. I know that you can create the effect using Clip-path, however, it will only work in Chrome/Safari and not Firefox and MS Edge/IE11.

Is there a way to recreate this so that it works across all newer browsers? I'm guessing it'll have to be a combination of Clip-path and SVG, yet I'm not sure how that'll be done.

```
-
```

Comment: Unless you are seeing something different than I am or don;t know what to look for. It works fine on Chrome, IE Edge and Firefox. All have the same behavior. I guess you are saying it doesn;t work on some other backgrounds ... perhaps it would be better to post a fiddle where it does not work